# Can't run PHP with JavaScript eventlistener

Tags: javascript, php, event-listener

Im using PHP to create a canvas to write and it will output text as result to a textarea(done by other functions). There are some other input tag too such as title etc to get input from users. The value/content from these input tag (title and textarea) will submit to the database with form method "post". However i have some buttons with event listener function attached for the canvas part ("undo" or "redo" strokes). The saving part already successful been done but the event listener part seems to not working, each time i press undo or redo the window will load like my submit button and my canvas wont undo or redo the strokes and i'm not sure what is wrong with the code, anyone can help me? The example of code is something as below:

```
<body>
<form method="something.php" method="post">
<label for = "datetime">Date Created:</label><br>
<input type="text" name="inputDate" size="20" disabled>   //disabled because i put timestamp
<input type= "submit" name = "submit" value="Save"></input>
<pre><textarea id="result" name = "res"></textarea></pre>    //the text will output here
</form>
<br><canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas><br>   //where my i draw
<button id="undo" class = "button" >Undo</button>
</body>

<script>
(function () 
{
var undo = document.getElementById('undo');
..
..
 undo.addEventListener('click', function () 
{
if (!inkRecog.isEmpty()) 
{
inkRecog.undo();    
}
doRecog();
},
 false);
 })();
</script>
```

my inkRecog.undo already declare in another form, previously working, but when i put the form method in the body it won't work.

//

Answer (score 0):

You need to

```
return false;
```

at the end of the event listener under doRecog();

Comment: dtanders:
Hi, i've tried. Still not working. Even my main function to draw on canvas is not working. Is it possible something to do with my form method? Or the position where i put my canvas and redo button at? (Oh, there's something i forgot to mention too, i will update my question.)

Comment: Maybe post a more complete example using the example code feature, then

Comment: I have already updated the description. Basically just i'm using my canvas to scribble word and it will output at the textarea then i got a "input type submit" button to save the date and the word in textarea to database. The "undo" event listener button is to undo the scribble, the main problem is when i use my submit button to save to database, my undo button won't work. But when i deleted that line "form method post" my undo button works but my save button doesn't works. Any idea how to solve?

Comment: Is the method that serializes your canvas out to to send to your server _also_ flattening the history, maybe?